# receives data from websocket on the Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools on a specific homepage

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am writing this question because I have a question while writing the current program.

If you go to the Chrome Developer Tools -> Network tab on a specific homepage, you are writing a program to receive this as a Node.js.

In the General tab of the Header
Request URL: wss://stream-live.bitsonic.co.kr:8443/socket.io/?streams=btckrw*ticker%2Fbtckrw*aggTrade%2Fbtckrw*depth_20&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=1p8mHxkKcBYxAvKVE1id

I am writing this program based on url as wss: // stream-live.bitsonic.co.kr:8443 /.

In the Query String Parameters tab,
streams: btckrw*ticker/btckrw*aggTrade/btckrw*depth_20
EIO: 3
transport: websocket
sid: 1p8mHxkKcBYxAvKVE1id

Contains the value.

Below is the program I wrote.

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket_url = 'wss://stream-live.bitsonic.co.kr:8443/';
var socket = io.connect(socket_url);
socket.on('connect', function(err, data){
console.log('Connected.1');
socket.emit('DEPTH',{
    query: {
        'streams': 'btckrw*ticker/btckrw*aggTrade/btckrw*depth_20',
        'EIO': '3',
        'transports': ['websocket'],  // ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'polling']
        // 'nonce': Date.now()*1000,
        'sid': 'UzCyjO_8gXPpPrcEEoEg'
    }
});
});

socket.on('error', function(data){
    console.log('err',data);
});

socket.on('close', function(data){
    console.log('cls',data);
});

socket.on('message',(body)=>{
    console.log('msg',body);
});
```

In the web socket tap, the contents of message is stacked on the Frames tab, and io.on ('message') is supposed to contain the content.

Below is the error content.

```
err:  { Error: xhr post error
    at XHR.Transport.onError (G:\dev\js\bsx\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transport.js:64:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (G:\dev\js\bsx\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:109:10)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (G:\dev\js\bsx\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:133:20)
    at Request.onError (G:\dev\js\bsx\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:309:8)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (G:\dev\js\bsx\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\polling-xhr.js:256:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5) type: 'TransportError', description: 403 }
```

I would really appreciate it if you let me know what went wrong.

And I apologize for my poor English ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to know that using socket.io is not the exact same thing as normal WebSocket

if I get what you want correctly then you should know that using

```
socket.on('message',(body)=>{
    console.log('msg',body);
});
```

is not the same as

```
let socket = new WebSocket('url');
socket.onmessage(callback) //or using addEventListener
```

in socket.io the `message` event should be defined by you and it's not automatic as I know

in normal WebSocket on `message` will listen to everything and check every request and response

hope you can get somewhere from my answer

Comment: Oh. Thanks for your help! @Louay Alosh

Comment: I'm a bit confused please clarify a bit

Comment: @Louay Al-osh I'm a bit confused please clarify.. I'm having this issue too